# Can I take cuttings out of a second year parsley plant and plant it as new?

Tags: herbs, cuttings, parsley

I have a parsley plant that managed to survive the winter. Since this second year is it's last, I'd like to plant a new one for the next two years. I was wondering if I can take a cutting from my second-year parsley, root it, and plant it - will it grow well for two years?

The other option would be to use its seeds, but for that I'd have to wait until the end of the second year, and also the plant will not grow as well if I let it flower & seed, so I was thinking of cutting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you take your cutting from stems without flowers. Also, not all cuttings of parsley mature to grow roots, so take several cuttings, and place them in clear water. Take care to snip off the lower leaves from the cuttings, so that those leaves don't get submerged and decompose. Place the water container with the parsley cuttings in a place where they would receive sunlight during the day, but take care so that their surrounding environment does not get too cold during the night, if needed by relocating the container every evening and morning. New roots should appear under some of the cuttings, and wait for those roots to grow at least 3-4 cm. Then, plant them outside in the soil.

Comment: Thanks! And will these cuttings, after planted, behave like new parsley plants (despite being cuttings from second-year plants)? ie, will the flower and die the same year or the following?

Comment: They should behave like new parsley plants and produce leaves on the first year as long as you are not taking your cutting from a stem that already has flowers.